# Visual Paradigm ER diagram adding tables

Tags: entity-relationship, visual-paradigm

I am designing  an ER diagram to simplify creating tables for my project.I want to add an attribute named phone-number which can hold more than one phone-numbers.How can I do it

Comment: Putting this question on hold for being too broad is silly.  My answer is not too long and there are no reasonable alternative answers unless you conflate a multivalued attribute with multiple single-valued attributes or one-to-many relationships in ER.

Comment: I agree I am satisfied by the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Paradigm doesn't really do ER diagrams, it just abuses ER terminology in its schema designer.  Dia is a tool that supports both ER diagrams and multivalued attributes.

To implement multivalued attributes in Visual Paradigm, you need to understand a part of how ER diagrams are translated to physical models.  In an ER diagram, we can indicate a customer with a multivalued attribute like so:

[image: ER diagram]

In a nested / unnormalized tabular model, it would look like this:

[image: Unnormalized table]

Eliminating repeating groups and choosing a suitable primary key gives us 1st normal form:

[image: 1NF table]

Then dealing with partial dependencies satisifies the rest of the normal forms:

[image: Normalized table]

From the normalized tables, you can see that to implement a multivalued attribute in a tabular schema design like those produced by Visual Paradigm, you should create a new table to represent the attribute (in ER an attribute is a mapping from an entity set to a value set, hence two columns are here used to represent one attribute).  The new table will have a composite primary key consisting of the entity's primary key and the attribute value:

[image: VP schema]